# pyodbc not recognised within komodo edit

Tags: python, pyodbc, komodoedit

pyodbc-3.0.6 does not appear to be recognised by Komodo Edit 7.
Following install instructions from http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/ the module is recognised through the command line interpreter; connects to SQL Server and generally behaves as expected.

However, when using Komodo Edit `import pyodbc` does not recognise the module and subsequently autocomplete is disabled. Not a fundamental problem in using the module but irritating to have the functionality disabled.

I'm running Python 2.7, 64-bit.

Background reading, suggests that Komodo is 32-bit and support for pyodbc is only available through upgrading to Komodo IDE and automated ActivePython module updates. Is it this simple or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Komodo uses [CIX (codeintel XML) files](http://support.activestate.com/faq/codeintel-cix-schema) that describe autocompletion information for binary libraries.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to locate one for pyodbc; you'd have to create such a file yourself. You can find [instructions on how to do that on in the Komodo FAQ](http://community.activestate.com/faq/generate-python-api-catalog):

```
svn co http://svn.openkomodo.com/repos/openkomodo/trunk/src/codeintel/support/gencix/python python_gencix
cd python_gencix
python gencix.py --onefile=pyodbc.cix --name="PyODBC" --description="Python ODBC module" pyodbc
```